# Azure Policy - Enable Auto Shutdown at VMs

Tags: azure, azure-policy

it is possible to activate the Azure VM Autoshutdown Function with an Azure Policy?

I found always articles with an DevTest Lab. But i would like to use an AZure Policy at the Production Subscription to can found VMs without an Azure AutoShutdown Configuration.

Thanks.

Best Regards,
Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm from the Microsoft for Founders Hub team. Auto Shutdown can be implemented on Azure VMs through Azure policy by following the JSON file available [here](https://github.com/tyconsulting/azurepolicy/blob/master/policy-definitions/deploy-vm-shutdown-schedule/azurepolicy.json) however remediation task has to be setup so that the option of Auto shutdown will be overridden by the policy if already configured.

JSON reference URL: https://github.com/tyconsulting/azurepolicy/blob/master/policy-definitions/deploy-vm-shutdown-schedule/azurepolicy.json